# Git restore from local object file

Tags: git, restore

at first sorry for my bad english

I hope someone can help

I have start the command : `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

A big misstake : the Problem is all my files is not on the gitlab server .

And not on my local Repo

But i can see the files is save in /.git/objects

Can i restore my git from /.git/objects

Is my repo save in objects ? or is now all deleted ?

Comment: Your english is properly fine. Take a look here http://superuser.com/questions/590224/undoing-a-git-reset-of-multiple-commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hrs@hrs-dev:~/hrs_dev$ git reflog
...
231fddb HEAD@{23}: HEAD~1: updating HEAD
c84881f HEAD@{24}: commit: add basde code

...
hrs@hrs-dev:~/hrs_dev$ git reset --hard c84881f
Checking out files: 100% (5723/5723), done.
HEAD is now at c84881f add basde code

Very thanks .
Git is so awesome:
The Problem is i must understand the commands ^^